# (Vue 3) Присвоение данных из props в data()

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Всем доброго времени суток)

Vue 3

В **products-carousel** передаю **newProducts** - массив(полученный через fetch запрос) содержащий 8 объектов.
Если передать этот массив дальше в **new-product**, то все работает.
Но реализуя кнопки т.к. не могу мутировать массив из **props**, я пытался в **data()** создать переменную **productsList** присвоив значение массива **newProducts**.
Но во Vue devtools он показывает что в **productsList** пустой массив.

```
  <div class="products-carousel">
    <button @click="spinCarousel('left')" class="button products-left">
      <svg
        height="32px"
        id="Layer_1"
        style="enable-background: new 0 0 128 128"
        version="1.1"
        viewBox="0 0 128 128"
        width="32px"
        xml:space="preserve"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <g>
          <line
            style="
              fill: none;
              stroke: #2f3435;
              stroke-width: 12;
              stroke-linecap: square;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            "
            x1="87.5"
            x2="40.5"
            y1="111"
            y2="64"
          />
          <line
            style="
              fill: none;
              stroke: #2f3435;
              stroke-width: 12;
              stroke-linecap: square;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            "
            x1="40.5"
            x2="87.5"
            y1="64"
            y2="17"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <new-product
      v-for="(newProduct, idx) in productsList"
      :key="idx"
      :newProduct="newProduct"
    />
    <button @click="spinCarousel('right')" class="button products-right">
      <svg
        height="32px"
        id="Layer_1"
        style="enable-background: new 0 0 128 128"
        version="1.1"
        viewBox="0 0 128 128"
        width="32px"
        xml:space="preserve"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <g>
          <line
            style="
              fill: none;
              stroke: #2f3435;
              stroke-width: 12;
              stroke-linecap: square;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            "
            x1="40.5"
            x2="87.5"
            y1="17"
            y2="64"
          />
          <line
            style="
              fill: none;
              stroke: #2f3435;
              stroke-width: 12;
              stroke-linecap: square;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            "
            x1="87.5"
            x2="40.5"
            y1="64"
            y2="111"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NewProduct from '@/components/NewProduct'

export default {
  name: 'ProductsCarousel',
  components: {
    NewProduct,
  },
  props: {
    newProducts: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      productsList: this.newProducts,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    spinCarousel(direction) {
      if (direction === 'right') {
        this.productsList.push(this.productsList.shift())
      }
      if (direction === 'left') {
        this.productsList.unshift(this.productsList.pop())
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ну по логике вроде всё правильно, только нужно бы ещё  `productsList: [ ...this.newProducts ],` (чтобы не получать потом неожиданные приколы). Но в целом должно и так работать. Вы уверены, что всё как надо в компонент передаётся (выше)?

Comment: Вроде все так. Если я `newProducts` передаю в компонент `new-product` минуя `productsList` то все ок. Не значит ли это что все нормально с `props` в компоненте из кода? Плюс во Vue devtools видно что в `props` как раз лежит `newProducts` содержащий массив с 8 объектами, но видно также что в `data()` есть пустой массив `productsList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью watch

Подскажите если кто знает по какой причине все таки не сработало обычное присвоение.

```
watch: {
    newProducts() {
      this.productsList = [...this.newProducts]
    },
  },
```